# how can the use of a function and a series of variables affect the value of other unrelated variables?

Tags: embedded, cmsis

I use the CMSIS-DSP library to calculate the Fourier transform, but when I want to calculate the magnitude, I run into a problem. This affects other data (a struct variables )and makes them 0 in the end, the whole program collapses. I don't understand what is the reason for this.

I used the function in the library(arm_cmplx_mag_f32) and wrote the function myself, and the result is the same for both cases.

I understand these in debugging mode

More precisely, for example, on a conversion with a length of 128, from the beginning of the calculation of the magnitude, the data of the other section will not be corrupted, but after the calculation of about 40 data magnitude, the other data(struct variables) will be corrupted and finally, the whole program will collapse.I want to know what happened, how can the use of a function and a series of variables affect the value of other variables?

here is the code i write :

```
void calculate_magnitude(float *fft_output,float *magnitude_output,uint32_t fft_size){
float real,imag;

    for( j = 0 ; j < fft_size ; j++ ){
        real = *fft_output++;
        imag = *fft_output++;
        *magnitude_output++= sqrtf( (real * real) + (imag * imag) ) ;    
    }
}
```

Comment: With the information that you have given, the most precise answer that can be made is "there is a bug in your program".  You have made some kind of mistake in your code.  My best guess would be that your are accessing an array out of bounds, but this is only a guess.

Comment: @TomV  I have no idea, because when I comment this line of code (calculate the fft magnitude ) everything is fine but when I use this function it crashes whether I use library functions or write the corresponding function myself.

Comment: Insufficient context.  Most likely `magnitude_output` points to something shorter than `fft_size` and you are stomping on memory that is not part of `magnitude_output`.  Is `j` truly external to this function?  If that is indicative of your code quality, this will not be the only bug I would bet

Comment: If `j` is global (a truly horrifying thought) and in proximity to whatever `magnitude_output` refers to, then this loop will not only overrun the output, but may modify `j` in _"interesting"_ ways, and cause the loop to terminate incorrectly (too late or too early) https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the edit to include the code, I think my guess in the comments was correct.

You do not show the declaration of `j`, but I guess it has a small type (eg `uint8_t`) and the value you pass to `fft_size` is greater than the maximum of that type (eg: greater than 255).  This means your loop will run forever, making the pointers overflow the arrays.

Alternatively in the general case, your pointer arguments do not point to valid arrays of the required type and/or size.

Comment: j is uint32_t type and fft_size=128, i program on MCU that has low memory I think it may be relevant to that. and  as  i say earlier i even use the CMSIS-DSP library that is a standard lib but the results are same.

Comment: @Ho3einHK Occam's razor applies.  If both `arm_cmplx_mag_f32` and `calculate_magnitude` fail, then the issue is with the code calling them.  You have not shown that.

Comment: @Clifford In fact, someone told me that it could be due to the use of pointers in both functions, and after writing the function without using pointers, the problem was solved, but I did not understand why this problem was created, that is, I think that at least the function that was in the CMSIS -DSP should work without problems.

Comment: @Ho3einHK for sure, but that does not mean the functions were in error, rather that the parameters (passed as _pointers_) were invalid.  It is likely that you are still passing the parameters as pointers, so not really "_without using parameters_" surely?.  Anyhow the appropriate response to my point is probably not to argue about it, but to post the missing information.  You may learn something useful in finding out what was wrong with _your_ code.  After all you could have "_somebody telling you_", or you could get eyes on it from the entire SO community.  My bet would be on the community.